# Calculate recall metric when StratifiedShuffleSplit is used

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

The following method uses the KNN classifier with StratifiedShuffleSplit since I have an imbalanced dataset:

```
def KNN(train_x, train_y):
    skf = StratifiedShuffleSplit()
    scores = []
    for train, test in skf.split(train_x, train_y):
        clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1)
        clf.fit(train_x.loc[train], train_y.loc[train])
        score = clf.score(train_x.loc[test], train_y.loc[test])
        scores.append(score)

    res = np.asarray(scores).mean()
    print(res)
```

How can I modify the `scores` to calculate the `recall` and `precision` metrics instead of the default accuracy?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score

def KNN(train_x, train_y):
    skf = StratifiedShuffleSplit()
    scores = []
    scores2 = []
    for train, test in skf.split(train_x, train_y):
        clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1)
        clf.fit(train_x.loc[train], train_y.loc[train])
        y_pred = clf.predict(train_x.loc[test]) # predict the labels of the test set
        y_true = train_y.loc[test] # get the true labels of the test test
        score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred) # recall estimation
        score2 = precision_score(y_true, y_pred) # precision estimation
        scores.append(score)
        scores2.append(score2)
```